# How to map json and skip parent property?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have this json string, which contains two elements each with a Number and a Status:

```
var jsonString = "{\"Errors\":[{\"Number\":9,\"Status\":\"BadRequest\"}, {\"Number\":3,\"Status\":\"BadConnection\"}]}";
```

As you see it has a parent property called **Errors**.

I have prepared this model:

```
public class ExceptionStructure
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Using NewtonSoft.Json I would like to deserialize the json string into an array of *ExceptionStructure* objects, without also having to create a model for the parent property (as I don't really need it).

Can I do this (perhaps with some json attribute on the model class)?

I was hoping to do something like this to deserialize:

```
var exceptionArr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExceptionStructure>(jsonString);
```

Comment: If only this `[{\"Number\":9,\"Status\":\"BadRequest\"}, {\"Number\":3,\"Status\":\"BadConnection\"}]` is your json you can do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExceptionStructure[]>(jsonString);` else you have to create another class to parse it explicit

Answer (score 2):

JSON.NET allows you to deserialize parts of a json file. You can do this by first deserialzing the json string to a JObject, extract the relevant parts, and then deserialize those to your actual object.

```
JObject errors = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

IList<JToken> results = errors["Errors"].Children().ToList();

IList<ExceptionStructure> exceptions = new List<ExceptionStructure>();

foreach (JToken result in results)
{
    ExceptionStructure exception= result.ToObject<ExceptionStructure>();
    exceptions.Add(exception);
}
```

Honestly though, in your case it might be easier to just build a Errors parent class

More information can be found at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Answer (score 2):

this is may be helpful you.

```
    string s = "{\"Errors\":[{\"Number\":9,\"Status\":\"BadRequest\"}, {\"Number\":3,\"Status\":\"BadConnection\"}]}";
    var jobj = JObject.Parse(s);
    List<ExceptionStructure> list = jobj["Errors"].ToObject<List<ExceptionStructure>>();
```

OR:

```
    string s = "{\"Errors\":[{\"Number\":9,\"Status\":\"BadRequest\"}, {\"Number\":3,\"Status\":\"BadConnection\"}]}";
    List<ExceptionStructure> list = JObject.Parse(s)
        .SelectToken("Errors")
        .ToObject<List<ExceptionStructure>>();
```